# Should i use Azure release pipeline for deployment or directly deploy from build pipelines by using a task?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, continuous-delivery

Azure DevOps has Pipelines (build) blade and Releases blade, deployment can be done by both either by creating a specific task in the build pipeline or by creating a new release in Releases, which one should i use?

I used both solutions and i belive using Releases is the cleaner approach

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi mazza, any update? did my post help?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that in your scenario, it's better to use [release pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/releases?view=azure-devops), as you could separate the building process and deploying process into different workflow.

If your artifacts are still under the debugging, you could just put it in the building pipeline without the deployment process. After you put the artifacts into deployment, when you need to optimize the artifacts, you only need to test in the build pipeline and won't effect the current success deployments. After you finish the debug, you only need to edit the artifact version in the release pipeline.
[image]

Even if you change the artifacts source for the deployment, you only need to change the artifact source and you don't need to create the deployment process again in single pipeline.
[image]

And once the debug has completed, you could use the release blade to test the artifacts in different deployment environments, without the building process(usually the building process would cost quite long time, especially when you have multiple artifacts).

Especially when you need to deploy the artifacts in different environment, creating the parallel stages could help you troubleshoot the stages one by one for different errors. Even one stage fails, the other deployments would still continue.
[image]
[image]

Comment: There is no reason to use a classic pipeline over a YAML pipeline at this point. Beyond that, this question is off-topic because it's soliciting opinions and should not have been answered.

Comment: release pipelines have a very different ui with advantages and disadvantages over yaml pipelines. so there may very well be reasons to use them. beyond that i agree that the question is too unspecific.